# Verb consistency of tense in extended passage

Tags: verbs, tenses

I read this answer on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Have-you-ever-lost-any-respect-for-someone-instantly#__w2_XOTYY6v_link). I wanted to ask about verb consistency because the writer is jumping from past continuous to present then present continuous.

How is doing that valid?

> I **was** in an Uber just last night. My girlfriend and I were going to a bar to meet friends for drinks and celebrate a birthday. The guy **pulls up** and my girlfriend **is finishing** her drink and says to him, “Don’t worry. It’s empty.” He smiles and says, “Don’t worry, it’s Vegas. You’re allowed to have fun!” We get in the car and he starts driving.

Comment: It is quite common to shift the temporal perspective in oral genres such as jokes and stories; it is an accepted convention in fiction, to make specific passages more 'immediate'; and it is not unknown even in the most formal narratives, such as scholarly histories.

Comment: I'd say the temporal perspective shift would be better in a new paragraph.

Comment: Jokes and Quora are two places *not* to expect conventional grammar, usage, or style. In any case, as StoneyB notes, the use of present forms to relate past events is fine, and known as the *narrative present* or *historical present*. In fact, were I telling the story, I would begin with *I'm in an Uber just last night…*